# ZipArchiveMode keep folder integrity

Tags: c#, zip, compression

I am trying to use the ZipArchiveMode to zip up a few files. The files are in different directories.

```
zipFile.CreateEntryFromFile(file, Path.GetFileName(file), compression);
```

I'm calling this for each file.

Is there a way to keep the folder integrity within the file so that it unzips in to the correct folder?

If not, do I have any other options for compressing files?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just `Path.GetFileName(file)`, use whatever portion of the fullname of the file is appropriate for your application.  Something like this might work:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
string path = fi.Directory.Parent + "\\" + fi.Name;
```

Comment: Ty for the response Jay. That makes sense, I was thinking it was a switch but it is storing it how it is being passed in. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your fi.Parent is not correct. I believe you meant `fi.Directory.Parent`. Even so, if you are multiple folders deep, your folder would end up being incorrect. I ended up using `var newpath = file.Substring(3, file.Length - 3);` to remove the `c:\ ` and that worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes it should have been `.Directory.Parent`, sorry about that. As for the path, yes use paths relative to your starting point.

Comment: ty but like I said, if I have a directory as such:  c:\dir1\dir2\dir3\file.txt then the only thing that it gets is the DIR2, which is not correct. So, I don't think your code is really working for what is needed, though it pointed me in the right direction.